# insert javascript into page

Tags: javascript

Im using internet explorer as the default browser. (Firefox is not an option). There are some web apps that I like but whose layout and workflow does not quite agree with me. Given that I am merely a visitor to the website, is it possible to insert jquery into the webpages Im browsing so that I can re-arrange the web content and call the javascript functions included ? Sorta like using jquery as a scripting language for IE ?

Comment: This is more of a superuser.com question.  Get your answer there and then come back here for help writing the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is something very similar to a bookmarklet. Find some popular bookmarklets and see how they pull in files and manipulate pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GreaseMonkey for Internet Explorer](http://www.gm4ie.com/)